# POSIX equivalent to prinf -v

Tags: bash, shell, sh, posix

I have a script that substitutes a variable with another value, depending on the input:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

prompt()
{
    while true; do
        read -p "Do you wish to install this program? " "ANSWER"
        case "$ANSWER" in
            [Yy]* ) printf -v "$1" %s "true"; break;;
            [Nn]* ) printf -v "$1" %s "false"; break;;
            * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
        esac
    done
}

prompt "QUESTION"
if [ "$QUESTION" = "true" ]; then
    echo "SUCCESS"
elif [ "$QUESTION" = "false" ]; then
    echo "FAILURE"
fi
```

This works fine, though i want the script to be POSIX compliant. I use `#!/bin/sh` for all my scripts, though `printf -v` is bashism. How can i modify this program? Is there an equivalent function i could use? Thanks!

Comment: FYI: `read -p` is a bashism as well. `printf "Do you ...? " >&2; read ANSWER`.

Answer (score 0):

`read` itself can set the variable whose name is in `$1`. However, you still need `read ANSWER` first, so that you can examine the response. Once it's done, you can use `read` and a here-document to transfer the value of `$ANSWER` to whatever variable `prompt` requests.

```
prompt () {
    while :; do
        printf "Do you wish to install this program? " >&2
        read ANSWER
        case $ANSWER in
          [Yy]* ) ANSWER=true ; break ;;
          [Nn]* ) ANSWER=false; break ;;
          * ) printf 'Please answer yes or no.\n' >&2 ;;
        esac
    done
    read "$1" <<EOF
$ANSWER
EOF
}
```

You can use a command substitution to ensure the `ANSWER` is not set in the global environment.

```
prompt () {
    read "$1" <<EOF
$(while :; do
    printf "Do you wish to install this program? " >&2
    read ANSWER
    case $ANSWER in
      [Yy]* ) printf true; break ;;
      [Nn]* ) printf false; break ;;
      * ) printf 'Please answer yes or no.\n' >&2 ;;
    esac
  done
)
EOF
}
```